# Activation link url pattern Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, thus the question. I'm sending the following activation link to users to activate their accounts.

http://localhost/api/v1/bouncer/activate?id=6&&token=AE8C448C50C5249CF56DFDE893E2F6DD

I'm a little lost as the url regex which will capture the id and the token value.
This is the url that I'm trying to build.

```
url(r'^activate/(<what goes in here>)', ActivationView.as_view(), name='activate')
```

This is the view,

```
class ActivationView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, key, user_id):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
            if key == profile.activation_key and profile.key_expires < datetime.datetime.now():
                user.is_active = True
                user.save()
                return Response(UserSerializer(user).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
        except(TypeError, ValueError, User.DoesNotExist):
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @OmarEinea how is that relevant, I have other urls there, but dont know how to compose this one.

Comment: @OmarEinea I've updated the question.

Comment: Your path doesn't have any dynamic elements so it is just '/api/v1/bouncer/verify'. (Although why you've put 'activate' there is confusing.)

Comment: That's a typo, editing the question.

Comment: Either way, you still don't have any dynamic elements in the path itself so your url is literally just `r'^activate$'`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure what you mean by dynamic elements, I've added the method that will handle this request. My question is how do I access the id and token value.

Comment: the `id` (and `token`) seem to be sent in a get request. so from your view, you can access it like this `request.GET['id']`